# parsing JSON of single video

Tags: android, json

i was trying to parse single video using json parser but no success can any one guide me to get title thump icon and rtsp link i tried till now to get title but i failed here is my code there is no response at all

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Perform a GET request to YouTube for a JSON list of all the videos by a specific user
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+id+"?v=2&prettyprint=true&alt=jsonc");
// Get the response that YouTube sends back
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
// Convert this response into a readable string
String jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
// Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

// For further information about the syntax of this request and JSON-C
// see the documentation on YouTube http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc.html

// Get are search result items
JSONObject jso = json.getJSONObject("data");
Toast.makeText(this, jso.getString("title"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: monika could you help me out here

Comment: please also share json string which you are getting in response

Comment: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/2b-NOjDcQfE/comments?v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=true  i wanna pass this link  i am not getting anything i don't know why i cannot see toast

Comment: i think jsonstring is empty i am not able to get anything in it